# How to debug this issue 'Error: connect ETIMEDOUT' in Postman

Tags: api, postman, postman-collection-runner

I have run the collection of requests with monitor feature in Postman. So, I had run this collection on the web-site and after some time I got an error in the console log:

```
18:47:35Preparing run.
18:47:35Running...Hide run logs
Line Number Timestamp   Console Output
1   18:47:35    SMOKE APP GW part 2 started
2   18:47:35    Get 'auth token' A
3   18:47:35    POST http://watch.test.com/app-gw/sandbox/login
4   18:49:45    Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.91.4.57:80
5   18:49:45    JSONError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
6   18:49:45    JSONError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
7   18:49:45    Get all services A
8   18:49:45    GET http://watch.test.com/app-gw/services?Authorization=6abbd51ee77c2112cce5b59587c7251c
9   18:51:56    Failed: Status code is 200
10  18:51:56    expected { Object (id, _details, ...) } to have property 'code'
11  18:51:56    Failed: Check the name of using service
12  18:51:56    object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but undefined given
13  18:51:56    Failed: Response time is less than 2000ms
14  18:51:56    expected undefined to be a number or a date
15  18:52:35    SMOKE APP GW part 2 finished
16  18:52:35    Error: callback timed out
18:52:35Run failed.
```

How can I debug this issue?